# add new set of incriminated numbers in different worksheet excel

Tags: excel, vba

Need help with creating an excel macro 
when you click on the new button it would look in sheet2 in column c row 2 and find the last number that was input and then add 1 and return that new number in cell D3

so in sheet2 column c row 2 would be CI300 and it would add CI301 underneath and return that number in sheet1 column d row 3

Ive been trying to find examples for the past 2 days on something similar found a few but only one was close but it had errors and was not the same

thanks

Comment: The input is unclear... Since your task - as described - may be achieved using simple formulas.

Comment: Can you specify your problem more clearly?

Comment: Is it always like CI### for the numbers? I mean is there any special pattern for those numbers?

Comment: how about simply placing this formula in the `Sheet1!D3`: `="CI" & (Right(Sheeet2!C2,3) +1)`

Comment: @ScottHoltzman:: Just one suggestion. Use `Mid` instead of `Right` `="CI" & (MID(Sheet2!C2,3,LEN(Sheet2!C2)-2) +1)` This will work for numbers like CI10000

Comment: @SiddharthRout -> Great point. I was being lazy and using OPs original pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work ...

```
Sub Btn_NextNum_Click()
Dim KeyStart As Range, LastNum, NewNum

    Set KeyStart = Sheets("Sheet2").[C2]   ' bad bad hard coding, but you asked for it
    If KeyStart(2, 1) = "" Then
        LastNum = KeyStart
    Else
        LastNum = KeyStart(KeyStart.End(xlDown).Row - 1, 1)
    End If

    NewNum = "CI" & Val(Mid(LastNum, 3)) + 1

    If KeyStart(2, 1) = "" Then
        KeyStart(2, 1) = NewNum
    Else
        KeyStart(KeyStart.End(xlDown).Row, 1) = NewNum
    End If

    Sheets("Sheet1").[D3] = NewNum         ' bad bad hard coding, but you asked for it

End Sub
```

Note I hate hard coding of cell addresses ... IMHO it would be better to use range names for the start of the key column and the output cell or direct the output to `Selection` so that the button places your NextNum whereever the cursor might be.

Comment: I want to thank every one that answered above but I was needing it to be after a button was pressed and not a formula in the cell which is what Mike has provided and works perfectly.

Comment: Mike thanks sooo much i guess name ranges will be good im gona try to do the name ranges myself and see if it works out and will post it back on here if i get it working